# Azure Table Storage Python SDK, Invalid syntax

Tags: python, azure, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, azure-table-storage

I was playing around with Azure Table service with their python SDK, the below given is a part of my code, but I believe the error comes from inside the SDK

```
from azure.storage import TableService, Entity
from datetime import datetime

ac_name = 'my_account_name'
primary_key = 'my_primary_key'
table_name = 'my_table_name'

def get_connection_string_and_create_table():
    global table_service
    table_service = TableService(account_name = ac_name,account_key=primary_key)
    table_service.create_table(table=table_name)
```

the code works fine when running in Windows but throws the following error when trying to run in Raspberry (running Raspbian OS)

```
from azure.storage import TableService, Entity
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/azure/storage/__init__.py" line 55
self.prefix = u''

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please help me out with this issue? :)  I'd be very much happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `u""` syntax for string literals was re-introduced [only in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), so as you're using Python 3.2 [you will get a syntax error](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

From [What's new in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-414-explicit-unicode-literals):

> To ease the transition from Python 2 for Unicode aware Python
>   applications that make heavy use of Unicode literals, Python 3.3 once
>   again supports the `“u”` prefix for string literals. This prefix has no
>   semantic significance in Python 3, it is provided solely to reduce the
>   number of purely mechanical changes in migrating to Python 3, making
>   it easier for developers to focus on the more significant semantic
>   changes (such as the stricter default separation of binary and text
>   data).

So, either get rid of the the `u''`(by default all strings are already unicode strings in Python 3) or upgrade Python 3 to a newer version to make it work.